# Elasticsearch doesn't return results on a multi match query

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I'm wondering why `Elasticsearch` doesn't give me any results for the following [Multi Match Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html):

```
GET /stag/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "phrase_prefix",
      "query":    "ferran ma",
      "fields": [ "fullName", "fullName.folded" ]
    }
  }
}
```

But it gives me results on:

```
GET /stag/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "phrase_prefix",
      "query":    "ferran may",
      "fields": [ "fullName", "fullName.folded" ]
    }
  }
}
```

I thought that maybe there is a minimum character length per word but then I've seen the following query:

```
GET /stag/_search
{
  "query": {
    "multi_match": {
      "type":     "phrase_prefix",
      "query":    "ignasi t",
      "fields": [ "fullName", "fullName.folded" ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is giving me results. So I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the problem is explained [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-match-query-phrase-prefix.html)

> The match_phrase_prefix query is a poor-man’s autocomplete. It is very
>   easy to use, which lets you get started quickly with
>   search-as-you-type but its results, which usually are good enough, can
>   sometimes be confusing.
>
> Consider the query string quick brown f. This query works by creating
>   a phrase query out of quick and brown (i.e. the term quick must exist
>   and must be followed by the term brown). Then it looks at the sorted
>   term dictionary to find the first 50 terms that begin with f, and adds
>   these terms to the phrase query.
>
> The problem is that the first 50 terms may not include the term fox so
>   the phrase quick brown fox will not be found. This usually isn’t a
>   problem as the user will continue to type more letters until the word
>   they are looking for appears.